# write a programme that reads 10 letter, After the letters have been read,Display the one that comes earliest in the alphabet

Tags: loops

how to write a programme that reads 5 letter, After the letters have been read,Display the one that comes earliest in the alphabet.

Comment: In what programming language? You should also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: many people can help you with your homework, but at least put some effort specifing what have you done, and the language you need it to be written.

Answer (score 0):

this should work in every language and it's maybe a good starting point.

write a loop, which reads 5 times a Character

store the Characters in a array

look at the integer value of this character (just google convert char to integer) and look at the ascii table

then you have found your solution